# Resize VFAT partition?

Tags: parted, vfat, partclone

I'm migrating a machine to another boot drive with more space. I've done the following:

```
sudo partclone.vfat -c -R -o partclone.sda1.vfat.img -s /dev/sdg1
```

and then I created my partitions on the new device in parted, and then restored:

```
sudo partclone.vfat -r -s partclone.sda1.vfat.img -o /dev/sdg1
```

The new partition is larger than the one I cloned from.

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sdg print 1

Minor: 1
Flags: 
File System: fat32
Size:         1074MB (0.11%)
Minimum size: 210MB (0.02%)
Maximum size: 1000GB (100%)
```

However, when I view the filesystem with `df`, it shows me something else:

```
$ sudo df -h extefi/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdg1       197M   42M  156M  22% /mnt/extefi
```

Is there a command I can run to properly resize the filesystem to fill its partition?

Answer (score 7):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/fatresize.1.html

`fatresize` is part of the `parted` package.

Comment: There is a [fatresize AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fatresize) for ArchLinux. I used it without issue.

Comment: In Debian (stretch at least) fatresize is its own package, not part of parted.

Comment: It uses `libparted`, Arch package description: A utility to resize FAT filesystems using libparted